# How to calculate effect size of permutation test of chi-square in R?

Tags: r, statistics, permutation, chi-squared

If I conducted a permutation test of chi-square test,
for example:

```
permudata = rbind(
  data.frame(x=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),c(8,8,31,4)),y="Freq1"),
  data.frame(x=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),c(4,12,31,4)),y="Freq2"))   
permudata$x = factor(permudata$x)   
permudata$y = factor(permudata$y) 
table(permudata)   
str(permudata)   
set.seed(1234)  
library(coin)   
chisq_test(y~x, data=permudata,
           distribution=approximate(nresample=9999)) # permutation test
(the output is:chi-squared = 2.1333, p-value = 0.5779)
```

How can I get its effect size (Cramer’s V for example)?
Should I just calculate its effect size in a normal way? like this:

```
data = rbind(  
  data.frame(x=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),c(8,8,31,4)),y="Freq1"),  
  data.frame(x=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),c(4,12,31,4)),y="Freq2")) 
data$x =factor(data$x) 
data$y = factor(data$y) 
a = table(data) 
chisq.test(a) ##chi-square 
N=sum(a);N      
library(lsr)  
cramersV(a)  ## cramer v
(the output is:X-squared = 2.1333, df = 3, p-value = 0.5452; Cramer's V = 0.1446203)
```

thanks all.

Comment: $Phi$ and Kramer's V don't seem to care where $Chi^2$ comes from. https://www.statology.org/effect-size-chi-square/

Comment: If I want to report the result, can i report like this: χ2 = 2.13, p = 0.58, Cramer's V = 0.14? I mean can I report the χ2 (that is not based on permutation), the p-value (based on permutation), and Cramer's V( that is not based on permutation) together?

Comment: The permutation is used only to compute the p-value, not the chi square or Cramer's V. If you want to provide confidence intervals for the Cramer's V statistic, the `CramerV()` function in package `DescTools` can do that: `CramerV(permudata$y, permudata$x, conf.level=.95)` returns a range of 0 to .289 for your sample data.